# How can I find all items beginning with a or â?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, internationalization

I have a list of items that are grouped by their first letter. By clicking a letter the user gets alle entries that begin with that letter.

This does not work for french. If I choose the letter a, items with â are not returned.

What is a good way to return items no matter if they have an accent or not?

```
                 <%  char alphaStart = Char.Parse("A"); 
                        char alphaEnd = Char.Parse("Z"); %>
                    <%  for (char i = alphaStart; i <= alphaEnd; i++) { %>
                        <% char c = i; %>
                        <% var abcList = Model.FaqList.Where(x => x.CmsHeader.StartsWith(c.ToString())).ToList(); %>
                        <% if (abcList.Count > 0 ) { %> 
                            <div class="naviPkt">
                                <a id="<%= i.ToString().ToUpper() %>" class="naviPktLetter" href="#<%= i.ToString().ToLower() %>"><%= i.ToString().ToUpper() %></a>
                            </div>
                            <ul id="menuGroup<%= i.ToString().ToUpper() %>" class="contextMenu" style="display:none;">
                                <% foreach (var info in abcList) { %>
                                    <li class="<%= info.CmsHeader%>">
                                        <a id="infoId<%= info.CmsInfoId%>" href="#<%= info.CmsInfoId%>" class="abcEntry"><%= info.CmsHeader%></a>
                                    </li>
                                <% } %>                                        
                            </ul>
                        <% } %>

                    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily remove the diacritic signs (accents, umlaut, cedilla and so on) from the string to test only on the base character. This is done by [normalizing the string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx) to Unicode form D and removing the character of category "NonSpacingMark". The following extension method strips a string of its diacritic signs :

```
    public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
        string formD = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        string noDiacriticsFormD = new string(
            formD.Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                 .ToArray());
        string noDiacritics = noDiacriticsFormD.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
        return noDiacritics;
    }
```

Using this method, your code becomes :

```
var abcList = Model.FaqList.Where(x => x.CmsHeader.RemoveDiacritics().StartsWith(c.ToString())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `i.ToString().ToUpper(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`. It uses a culture neutral model for case conversion, which should eliminate accents.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to LBushkin's answer (which I think will work), you can clean up your alphabet generation.

```
var A = Char.Parse("A");
var alphabet = Enumerable.Range(0, 26).Select(i => A + i);
```

Then you can use a foreach loop and forget the whole `c = i` thing. Also you don't need the `.ToUpper()` calls because you already have capital lettters.